# Vaadin 8 PushMode.MANUAL - What is this mode used for?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, push-technology

[Vaadin Framework 8](https://vaadin.com/framework) offers built-in support for [Push technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) as discussed [in the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html).

We can specify any of [three modes](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.2/docs/api/com/vaadin/shared/communication/PushMode.html), one of which is [`PushMode.MANUAL`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.2/docs/api/com/vaadin/shared/communication/PushMode.html#MANUAL), documented as:

> Push is enabled. A bidirectional channel is established between the client and server and used to communicate state changes and RPC invocations. The client is not automatically updated if the server-side state is asynchronously changed; ui.push() must be explicitly called.

If the whole point of Push is to automatically update the client, **why would we ever want to use this mode**?

Comment: For example when you wish to push every 5 minutes (and not always). It's a load question

Answer (score 4):

Both modes keep a communication channel open so that updates *can* be sent from the server to the client at any time, compared to `PushMode.DISABLED` that only can send updates to the client in the response to a request that the client has opened as a reaction to user activity.

The difference lies in when this capability is actually used. With `PushMode.AUTOMATIC`, updates are sent whenever the session is unlocked, i.e. after running pending `ui.access()` tasks that have been scheduled from a background thread.

No update is sent if nothing has changed, but checking for this situation still has some overhead. There might also be situations when lots of fine-grained `ui.access()` tasks are run in rapid succession, but it's not desirable to send them all as individual updates to the client.

The purpose of `PushMode.MANUAL` is to give the application developer control over when changes are actually sent by explicitly calling `ui.push()`. This makes it possible to better optimise resource consumption in in cases when the automatic mode would cause excessive pushing. This is quite rarely needed, but the possibility does still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I found the MANUAL mode doesn't really show the updated/pushed value directly, and it waits till the UI is "refreshed"

Meaning, if you hide and show the value gets refreshed to the latest, otherwise left hidden.

This is observation only, I haven't yet drilled into the technical details yet.